Why one uses async AND defer simultanously?
I see from time to time, people use async and defer simultanously for same (third-party) scripts. Why one does this? Aren't async and defer thought for completely different cases?

defer :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer  If the attribute is specified with the async attribute, the element will act as if only the async attribute is specified.

It's an old technique for when the async attribute wasn't well supported (IE supported defer until IE 10 but not async, but even then it only supported defer badly).
Unfortunately it's now bad advice as it means defer is ignored as per MDN linked in fdomnn-m's comment:

defer
If the attribute is specified with the async attribute, the element will act as if only the async attribute is specified.

And usually you want the more powerful defer as opposed to async.
So people should stop doing this.

Other useful links: can I use: defer and can I use: async confirms
